# MySQL Update Trigger: new.value y old.values son diferentes pero cuando se comparan en un IF dentro del trigger son iguales

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo este Trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`telexes_sc`@`%` TRIGGER `telexes_system`.`crm_inventory_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `crm_inventory` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("new-imei2: ", 
IFNULL(new.imei_2,"NULL")));
INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("old-imei2: ", IFNULL(old.imei_2,"NULL")));
IF new.imei_2 != old.imei_2 THEN
    INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values ("Columna modificada imei2");
    IF NOT ISNULL(new.imei_2) THEN    
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values ("La columna imei2 es NOT null");
        SET @totalimei = ( SELECT count(*) FROM crm_inventario WHERE imei = new.imei_2 );
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("Comparando imei = new.imei_2 / @totalimei: ", @totalimei));        
        IF @totalimei > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'imei_2 ya existe en otro artículo del inventario, ya sea en el campo imei o imei_2, ¡corríjalo!';     
        END IF;
        SET  @totalimei2 = (SELECT count(*) FROM crm_inventario WHERE imei_2 = new.imei_2);
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("Comparando imei_2 = new.imei_2 / @totalimei2: ", @totalimei2));
        IF @totalimei2 > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'imei_2 ya existe en otro artículo del inventario, ya sea en el campo imei o imei_2, ¡corríjalo!';     
        END IF;        
    END IF;
END IF;


INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("new-imei: ", IFNULL(new.imei,"NULL")));
INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("old-imei: ", IFNULL(old.imei,"NULL")));
IF new.imei != old.imei THEN
    INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values ("Columna modificada imei");
    IF NOT ISNULL(new.imei) THEN    
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values ("La columna imei es NOT null");
        SET  @totalimei = (select count(*) FROM crm_inventario WHERE imei = new.imei);
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("Comparando imei = new.imei / @totalimei: ", @totalimei));
        IF  @totalimei > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'imei ya existe en otro artículo del inventario, ya sea en el campo imei o imei_2, ¡corríjalo!';     
        END IF;
        SET  @totalimei2 = ( SELECT count(*) FROM crm_inventario WHERE imei_2 = new.imei );
        INSERT INTO milog (mensaje) values (concat("Comparando imei_2 = new.imei / @totalimei2: ", @totalimei2));
        IF  @totalimei2 > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'imei_2 ya existe en otro artículo del inventario, ya sea en el campo imei o imei_2, ¡corríjalo!';     
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;

END
```

La sintaxis de la tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE `crm_inventory` (
  `id_inventario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imei` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `imei_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_inventario`),
  KEY `imei` (`imei`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

La idea es que los valores de las columnas `imei` e `imei_2` no puedan repetirse en ninguna de las 2 columnas, **EXCEPTO** cuando sean nulos.

Algunos datos de la tabla `crm_inventory` son:

| id_inventario | imei | imei_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 357079108594626 | null |
| 4 | 357079108595425 | null |
| 5 | 357079108596092 | null |
| 6 | 357079108597488 | null |
| 7 | 357079109888233 | null |

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto esta actualización:

```
UPDATE crm_inventory
SET imei_2 = '357079108597488'
WHERE id_inventario = 4;
```

El trigger no hace nada y permite guardar el registro, pero debería dar el error, porque el registro con el `id_inventory 6`, en su columna `imei` tiene el mismo dato `357079108597488`.

Como he estado buscando durante mucho tiempo la razón de este error, puse el código para registrar en una tabla (milog) los valores de `new` y `old`, así como otras variables para saber qué pasaba. Pero sorprendentemente al hacer un:

```
SELECT * FROM milog;
```

inmediatamente después de ejecutar la actualización el resultado es:

| id | mensaje |
| --- | --- |
| 149 | new-imei2: 357079108597488 |
| 150 | old-imei2: NULL |
| 151 | new-imei: 357079108595425 |
| 152 | old-imei: 357079108595425 |

Así que en la línea donde comparo

```
IF new.imei_2 != old.imei_2 THEN
```

el valor de retorno es falso y **SON DIFERENTES** al menos así lo registro en la tabla milog, registro 149 y 150. ¡Aquí estoy realmente confundido!.

La verdad es que he cambiado miles de cosas desde operadores `<>` por `!=` o incluso `&&` por `AND` o `IF` anidados cuando solo tenía un `IF`, o `= null` por `ISNULL`, en fin, muchas cosas, hasta conseguir este horrible Script que aún **NO** funciona y lo peor es que no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

He trabajado en otras bases de datos y esta la resuelvo rápidamente sin problemas.

Cuando ejecuto

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

el resultado es:

| variable_name | value |
| --- | --- |
| innodb_version | 5.7.40 |
| protocol_version | 10 |
| slave_type_conversions |  |
| tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version | 5.7.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
| version_comment | (Ubuntu) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64 |
| version_compile_os | Linux |

Comment: agradeceria si esto se pueda colocar en: http://sqlfiddle.com/ para una mejor comprension, respuesta y desarrollo.

Comment: Estás validando cada campo contra su valor anterior, no contra el otro campo "para que no sean iguales".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que si esperas que funcione el código correspondiente al bloque del `IF new.imei_2 != old.imei_2`, este nunca se ejecutará cuando `old.imei_2` sea `NULL`, que es el caso que estás dando en tu ejemplo. Esto es fácil de verificar:

```
select IF('imei' != NULL, 'Son diferentes', 'Son iguales')   as 'imei != NULL',
       IF( NULL != '#imei', 'Son diferentes', 'Son iguales') as 'NULL != imei',
       IF( NULL = NULL, 'Son iguales', 'Son diferentes')     as 'NULL = NULL'
  ;
```

| imei != NULL | NULL != imei | NULL = NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Son iguales | Son iguales | Son diferentes |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rbL408wK)

Los valores `NULL` son especiales, representan ausencia de un dato, por lo que comparar con este tipo de valor es comparar un dato contra algo que no existe.

Si quieres considerar los valores `NULL` como distintos a cualquier otra cadena e iguales en caso de que las dos columnas sean `NULL`, la forma de cubrir estos casos sería algo así:

```
IF (new.imei_2 != old.imei_2
    OR (new.imei_2 IS NULL and old.imei_2 IS NOT NULL)
    OR (new.imei_2 IS NOT NULL and old.imei_2 IS NULL)
    )
```

O bien usar `ifnull()` pero tienes que establecer un valor para estos casos que no se de en la práctica:

```
IF (ifnull(new.imei_2, 'NULL') != ifnull(old.imei_2, 'NULL'))
```